# How can I use PlayerPrefs to save the color values of the object?

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, colors

I'm trying to save the object's color based on what the user chooses and the load them back onto the screen on a key press. With some help from the answers, I managed to find a way to save color RGB values with PlayerPrefs, however, I'm not sure how to set "colorObject" to the object's current color. I've seen solutions where new Color() and predefined sets of colors are used, but I want to save what the user chooses. Is there a way to set "colorObject" to the current color of the object?

```
     /* Changing the color via key presses
     * 
     */

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        rend.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
    {
        rend.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.green);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
    {
        rend.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.blue);
    }
}

// To add button elements to the visual interface
void OnGUI() 
{
    // Saving
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(700, 330, 50, 30), "Save"))
    {
        // Saving the object's color 
        Color colorOfObject = new Color();
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("rValue", colorOfObject.r);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("gValue", colorOfObject.g);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("bValue", colorOfObject.b);
    }

    // Loading
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(770, 330, 50, 30), "Load"))
    {
        Color colorOfObject = new Color(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("rValue", 1F), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("gValue", 1F), PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("bValue", 1F));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Awake`, get a reference to the `GameObject`'s renderer:

```
private Renderer rend;

void Awake() {
    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
}
```

Save the red, blue, green, and--if you need it--alpha channels of the color as different float preferences:

```
// Saving
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(700, 330, 50, 30), "Save"))
{
    Color colorOfObject = rend.material.GetColor("_Color");

    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("rValue", colorOfObject.r);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("gValue", colorOfObject.g);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("bValue", colorOfObject.b);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("aValue", colorOfObject.a);
}
```

And then to load it, use `GetFloat` accordingly:

```
// Loading
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(770, 330, 50, 30), "Load"))
{
    Color defaultColor = Color.red;
    Color colorOfObject = new Color(
            PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("rValue", defaultColor.r),
            PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("gValue", defaultColor.g),
            PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("bValue", defaultColor.b),
            PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("aValue", defaultColor.a)
        );

    rend.material.SetColor("_Color", colorOfObject);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the code for saving the rgb values, however, i get this error message "Use of possibly unassigned field r". What does this mean??

Comment: It means you need to assign something to `colorOfObject` You need to assign whatever color you want to save to `colorOfObject`.

Comment: I saw some solutions that make a new Color() or use a predefined color, but I need to save the current object's color (which can vary based on what the user chooses) so I'm guessing that's not the solution. Is there a way to save the gameObject's current color??

Comment: @Karen Well, `gameObjects` don't have a color as such. They might have a component attached to them that has a color that you're interested in. You should edit your question to include information about exactly which color you're interested in getting. Currently, there isn't enough information to answer that part of your question.

Comment: Ah ok, I will go ahead and edit my question with additional code, thanks!!

Comment: @Karen I edited my answer to include how to get and set the `_Color` color on the renderer's material. I also changed my part on how to load a bit for a more convenient time setting the default values.

Comment: Ah ok, so I noticed that I defined "Renderer rend..." in my "void Update()" section of my code. Do I need to define another "Renderer rend..." in my "void OnGUI()" section of my code as well? (I'm assuming that the compiler will complain about using rend in the "void OnGUI()" section)

Comment: what I would do is add a `private Renderer rend;` field in your class, assign to it with `rend = GetComponent...` in `void Awake()` and then you should be able to use it just fine as usual in `void Update()` and `void OnGUI()`. `GetComponent` is an expensive call, so it's best to keep it out of `void Update()` whenever possible, so you don't have to make an expensive call every single frame.  If you aren't using `GetComponent` please ignore that last part, but you can still do the `private Renderer rend;` field.

Comment: @Karen I edited my answer to include some code to show the sort of thing I'm talking about.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. And when you say void Awake(), are you talking about void Start()?

Comment: Either one will work, but `Awake` is called before `Start` so it's good for things that want to happen before other things interact with that object in their `Start` and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this;

```
public static void SaveColor (Color color, string key) {
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(key + "R", color.r);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(key + "G", color.g);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(key + "B", color.b);
}

public static Color GetColor (string key) {
    float R = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(key + "R");
    float G = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(key + "G");
    float B = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(key + "B");
    return new Color(R, G, B);
}
```

or you can save it's hex code as string and load it